# how to put condition for child object in case of @ManyToOne join in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

```
@Entity    
public class Contact{
@id
private long id;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "account_id")
private Account account;}
```

Along with contact object i want to fetch account object only if account.deleteFlag=false is there, how to do please tell me. in case of @OneToMany relation @where Annotation is there but for @ManyToOne relation i got  solution like @JoinFormula but it is not working.

Comment: You say you tried @JoinFormula but it didn't work - can you please provide the implementation you tried there as well as the issues with it?

Comment: @ManyToOne
 @JoinColumn(name = "account_id", columnDefinition = "bigint") @JoinFormula("select * from Account where deleteFlag=false")
 private Account account;

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately `@Where` is not supported for `@ManyToOne` mappings - if you want to always exclude all `Account` instances which have been deleted everywhere you can add the `@Where` annotation above the `Account` class itself like so:

```
@Entity
@Where(clause = "deleteFlag=0")
public class Account { ... }
```

Comment: Contact have account_id that's why it finds for account with that account_id then it will throw exception like javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find Account with id 2